# Is it possible to take automated multiple exposure stop pictures with a Canon Rebel

Tags: canon, hdr, bracketing

The camera type that I have is the Canon Rebel Xsi, and I was wondering if it is possible to take an automated series of variable exposure shots. For example, hold the shutter button down once, and take a series of three or so pictures, each with a different exposure of -2, 0 and +2. To clarify, this is for the purpose of HDR photography.

If this isn't possible with this camera type, are there any brands/models that can do this?

Comment: This is called "bracketing". Multiple exposure refers to a single frame exposed more than once (usually leaving superimposed images).

Comment: See also [What Budget DSLR has bracketing modes?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11685/what-budget-dslr-has-bracketing-modes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. I think its named AEB (Auto Exposure Bracketing) on the Xsi menu. (On newer models it's Expo.comp/AEB) The Rebel Xsi supports up to -2 and +2. You will have to set your camera to manual or Av (Aperature Priority) as the AEB menu option will not be available under Auto.

Comment: Awesome, I just had a little slip up with the terminology thanks.